# Covr leads to error when building coverage for gitlab

Tags: r

I recently ran into the following error when executing `covr::gitlab()` on any of my R packages.

```
Error: Error in -stats$Relevant : invalid argument to unary operator
```

Does anyone of you have an idea what might be the problem?

Thanks! Using `covr@3.6.1`

Comment: Is `(()` intentional?

Comment: no, fixed it. Thanks for pointing this out